# causal effects when y is continuous and discontinuous over time

Tags: regression, linear-model, causality, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am interested in estimating the causal effects of A(treatment) on Y(outcome). Here treatment is a binary variables (yes vs no). Outcome is a continuous variable(weight), and this is normalized to Z scores. The main issues is outcome , not measured at all time intervals. When the time range spans is from 1994-2019. Outcome is measured between 1994-1999 and 2002-2019. Outcome is not measured between 1999-2002. My question is , how do I analyze data where y is discontinuous in time. What are the precautions necessary before fitting linear or any suitable models for this type of data ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plot you provide I do not see a significant trend of body weight over time.

You can try to fit a regression to see if the coefficient of time is significant statistically (p value) or practically (effect size compared to outcome scale). My guess is it won't be, so you can just proceed to calculate average treatment effect.

If your no-treatment group is not randomly assigned, and it's not a good natural experiment setting to begin with, you should consider using causal inference techniques such as propensity score matching to reduce the bias from the assignment mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are correct, fitting a simple linear trend line did not indicate any trend in either Treatment=Yes or Treatment=No groups.  Both group show a flat line neither increasing or decreasing with time.

Comment: This question is partially out of curiosity and partially closing the loop on this conversation, what if the slopes are not parallel ? what then ?

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai Short answer is to use the detrended values, i.e. the residuals of the regression, to calculate the average treatment effect. Note that this impacts variance calculation. You can look for regression adjustment for causal effect estimation for more reading on it.